# EF Core 2.1 - No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I have ASP.Net Core 2.1 with EF Core 2.1. This is how my DbContext class looks like

**app.DAL.EF** -> Layer

```
using app.domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace app.EF
{
 public class MyAppContext : DbContext
 {
    public MyAppContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppContext> options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("app");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
 }

   public class MyAppContextConfiguration : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppContext>
   {
    public MyAppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, true)
                                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ") ?? "Production" }.json", optional: true)
                                            .Build();

        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppContext>();
        //optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        var dbConString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ITMDbConnection");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(dbConString);

        return new MyAppContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}}
```

**app.DI** -> Layer

```
  public static class Factory
  {
    public static void Initialize(ref IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddTransient<MyAppContext>();
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
        {

        });
        //services.AddTransient<MyAppContextConfiguration>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
    }
}
```

app.API -> Layer

```
 namespace app.api
 {
 public class Startup
 {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Factory.Initialize(ref services);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}}
```

When running `Add-Migration DbInit` from Package Manager Console, throwing the below error

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

[image: error]

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What database is this supposed to use? Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL? Where will it connect to? A local database, a remote one, AWS RDS? You need to specify the provider and connection inside `AddDbContext`. Which, btw, should be in `Startup.cs`. Those methods are DI configuration methods, not factories or layers. If you want to simplify your code you could create an extension method that receives *and* returns an  `IServiceCollection`, alowing you to chain config calls just like other DI config methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Isn't the same mentioned in `MyAppContextConfiguration ` class?

Comment: You aren't using `CreateDbContext` anywhere. This code is a bit overcomplicated. Those classes, methods aren't layers, they are just a DbContext and some startup config *methods*. The DbContext configuration and DI registration is performed by `AddDbContext`. A simple `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ITMDbConnection"))` in there would work. The `MyAppContextConfiguration` class isn't used anywhere in Startup.cs

Comment: The host builder in ASP.NET Core 2.x and 3.x already perform the config steps in `CreateDbContext` - load `appsettings.json`, any environment files etc. This means that the `Configuration` field in `Startup.cs` can load the connection strings

Comment: if I use this `options.UseSqlServer()` in Factory or Startup class. Then tight coupling is being introduced

Comment: There is no tight coupling. Neither the context nor its consumers contain **any** reference to the configuration. `Startup` is for startup configuration, that's its job.

Comment: you need specify connection string like this 
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if so then we are viloating `DRY`

Comment: If anything, `Factory` is tightly coupled. `CustomerConfiguration` is extremely tightly coupled - it has to know about Customer but ends up just specifying a key that's already used by convention. It's not even needed.

Comment: No, you're violating that now. You're repeating configuration code in other classes. And `CustomerConfiguration` duplicates the convention that says the `Id` field is the primary key

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos CustomerConfiguration is a hypothetical class for sharing here

Comment: Instead of trying to "fix" ASP.NET Core or EF Core, use it first, understand how it works. It was created by many of the people that **created** the SOLID principles. A lot of those guys worked or still work at Microsoft.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [Design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory) is one of the valid [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) options. OP implements that pattern in their `MyAppContextConfiguration` class, so the question here is why EF Core tools are not using it, while "by design" they should.

Comment: @Kgn-web Can you run the PM command with `-verbose` option and show the output?

Comment: @IvanStoev that's why posting images instead of text is a **bad** idea. The most prominent warning in that image is a version discrepancy. The EF Core tools are out of date (2.1.1 instead of the runtime version, 2.1.14).

Comment: Of course the code shown does not configure db context in `services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>`, so you'll get the same exception at run-time. But it should work at design time.

Comment: @Kgn-web try updating the EF Core tools to 2.1.4, do you still have this problem? The image you posted shows the tools are 2.1.1, a 2-year old version while the runtime is 2.1.14

Answer (score 2):

Inside ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

In appsettings.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "SQL connection string"
    }
}
```

Comment: but the same is mentioned in `MyAppContextConfiguration` class

Comment: @Kgn-web mentioned, yes. Executed, no

Comment: Can you/we find a way to call CreateDbContext() to do so?

Comment: already tried with `services.AddDbContext<MyAppContextConfiguration()` throwing some other error

Comment: It look like your code first is point to app.EF, how about the startup project? If your start up project is app.EF, it get connection string from app.EF. else it get from your startup project config file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

You need to add base(options) to your constructor.

```
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

This will pass trough the options parameter to the base constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.14", I changed to the 7.0.4.
Then I also added

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Then it started to work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is easactly what it says - there is no database provider attached.

Look at all your code. Where do you specify the database provider? Something like UseSqlServer (in OnConfiguring of the DbContext), depending on what database provider you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear - the provider and connection are never configured. All this code could be replaced with this context :

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public MyAppContext(){}

    public MyAppContext(DbContextOptions<MyAppContext> options)
        :base(options)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //The base method is empty
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("app");
    }
 }
```

And a call to `AddDbContext` inside `ConfigureServices` :

```
 public class Startup
 {
     public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
        {
            var dbConString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ITMDbConnection");
            options.UseSqlServer(dbConString);
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    ....

}
```

Most applications have more than one DbContext though. One option would be to add another method to `Startup.cs` to register them. For more complex applications, eg applications composed of different domains/modules/subsystems/projects, a better idea would be to create extension methods, eg :

```
public static CustomerDomainExtensions
{
    public static IServicesCollection AddCustomerDomain(this IServicesCollection services,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return services.AddCustomerContexts(configuration)
                       .AddRepositories(...)
                       ...;

    }

    public static AddCustomerContexts(this IServicesCollection services,IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var dbConString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ITMDbConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(dbConString);
        });
        //Add more contexts ...
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, this would be called inside `ConfigureServices`. This is how all `Microsoft.Extensions.*` classes work, by providing `Add` and `Use` extension methods for use in `Startup.cs`  :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCustomerDomain(Configuration);


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

**EDIT**

Added a default constructor to the DbContext

Comment: if so can you add what is the usage of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>`

Comment: This interface is needed only if a DbContext doesn't have a default constructor. The solution to this is to add a default constructor. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-3.1): `Implement this interface to enable design-time services for context types that do not have a public default constructor. `